# Python GET request returns 403 Access Denied. Headers are used. Page is accessible via browser

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to get HTML response in Python with `requests`, but only get `403`. While in Chrome browser link works fine and page is loaded: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-ek1RYjR0NnNuandqYVQ1NjdUMm9IZz090/overview

I've copied exact headers of the successfully loaded page from Chrome Developer Tools-> Network recording, but no luck (below).

```
import requests

headers = {
'authority': 'www.dell.com',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-language': 'en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-ek1RYjR0NnNuandqYVQ1NjdUMm9IZz090/overview', headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Also, `requests.get('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us?lwp=rt')` returns 200 with no problem.

Can't figure out what the difference between a browser and a python request might be in this case.

UPD Python 3.7.3 running from Jupyter Notebook, but yes, that hardly matters. And I tried running Python console as well.

Comment: I have tried your code above and it works fine, the response code I got is `200`. What IDE are you using in running the code?

Comment: I'm trying from Jupyter Notebook. But, your answer gave me the idea to try it from somewhere else. So I did try from the command line, and still got 403.

Comment: I also tried your exact code, just pasted it, saved as code.py and `python code.py`. 200 response. Using python 3.10 (not that it should matter).

Comment: @Matthias and also George.
Thank you for your responses. That gave me some thoughts. and I tried to use US VPN, and yes, that time I got 200. That's not super convenient. And that leaves me wonder, what's wrong with my current Fi location. And still, how can Dell site tell the difference between browser and python request, since I copied headers?

Comment: that's a very good question, there must be some difference in the requests, what it is I do not know

Comment: maybe you can output the requests somehow and compare them, I know in the browser's developers tools you can look at the Network tab